# SQL Query Count across 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

Here is what I have (i am including only the relevant cells to each table)

```
table1:
 - user_id

table2:
 - id
 - manager_id
```

... and I have a PHP variable

```
$manager_id
```

So, what I am trying to do is get a COUNT(*) of how many records exist in table1, but the record should only be counted if table1.user_id (which is the table2.id) has a table2.manager_id == $manager_id

So, the only way I know how to do this would be to do something like this in PHP (which is wildly inefficient):

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE {my where clause}";
// execute query and place into $item[] array (not shown for brevity)
foreach ( $item as $user_id ) {
$query = "SELECT manager_id FROM table2 WHERE id = '{$user_id}';
// execute query, place each item into $row
if ( $row['manager_id'] == $manager_id ) {
// tick up count by 1
}
```

I am fairly certain there is a way to do this purely in SQL, but I am at a loss.

Comment: Join table2 on table1 on table1.userId = table2.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below query:

```
select count(1) from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.user_id = t2.id and t2.manager_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE manager_id = <your-value-of-manager-id>
)
```

In case you need to use the data and want to count on PHP side you can use the following `SELECT` statement using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.id 
WHERE table2.manager_id = <your-value-of-manager-id>
```

---

To execute the `SELECT` statements you should use prepared statements (using [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)).

**example using the first query:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE manager_id = ?)';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute([$manager_id]);

$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

if (count($rows) === 1) {
    echo $rows[0][0];
}
```

**example using the second query:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT table1.* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.id WHERE table2.manager_id = ?';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute([$manager_id]);

$rows = $sth->fetchAll();

echo count($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your where clause to have this condition i.e. 
SELECT Count(user_id) FROM table1 where
table1.user_id = table2.id 
AND Convert('Varchar', table2.manager_id) = $manager_id

I assume your php variable $manager_id has a string
if it is not a number then there is no need to convert the sql column (table2.manager_id) to varchar.